# Is the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} {i}^{-x}$ equal to $0$, or doesn't exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Can someone show me if this limit exists:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} {i}^{-x}=0$$
or it doesn't exist?

Here, $i$ is the unit imaginary part.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Consider the expression for $x$ an integer.

Comment: x: is real number

Comment: But if something goes wrong with integers only, is there any hope? You'll keep spinning in the unit circle.

Answer (score 5):

After choosing a branch $\log z$ of the complex log, you will get
$$i^{-x}=e^{-x\log i}.$$
Then $\log i= \ln|i|+i\arg i $, so
$$i^{-x} = e^{-x(\ln|i|+i\arg i)}=e^{-ix\arg i}$$
(since $\ln|i|=\ln 1=0$) .  We can assume $i$ has a well-defined argument in the given choice of branch, so that its argument is a constant value in whatever branch you select, say $\arg i=\theta$. Then, using Euler's identity, you get:
$$i^{-x}=e^{-x \ln i}=e^{-x(0+i\theta)}=e^{-ix\theta}=(\cos(x\theta)+i\sin(x\theta)).$$
Since $e^{i\cdot 0}=1 $ is fixed, the radius is fixed and you have a point in the unit circle.

As others pointed out, when $x$ grows, for a fixed value of $\theta$, the expression: $\cos(x \theta)$ and $\sin(x\theta)$ , the positions (angles) within the unit circle will oscillate indefinitely (e.g., let $x=p/q\pi\theta$ for the "right" values of $p,q$ ; can do something a bit different if $\theta =0$ ), so the argument (complex) part of the expression $i^{-x}=U+iV$ will not converge, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: I realized I messed up by confusing $ a^x =e^{xlna}$ with the wrong result that $a^x= e^{alnx}$. I am trying to fix it.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Named math operators should appear upright, and the common ones have their own code for this purpose (e.g. `\sin`, `\log` - [see entry 11 in our MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264)).

Comment: So , you are downvoting for incorrect editing? And without warning?

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Comment: Ok, sorry, it pisses me off to have these anonymous downvotes.

Comment: it hapens so often  downvotes by those who do not understand the post--maybe I can explain it to you downvoter, as slowly as needed.

Answer (score 3):

$i^{-x} = \frac{1}{i^x}=(\frac{1}{i})^{x} = (-i)^x$. Now observe that $i = e^{\pi i/2} \implies (-i)^x = e^{3\pi i x /2}$. So informally, as $x$ gets larger and larger, you just keep spinning around on the unit circle.

Comment: can I  keep spinning around on the unit circle. for :lim(cosx) ,x go to infty ?

Comment: That limit doesn't exist either - it should just bounce back and forth between -1 and 1.

Comment: lim(-isin(x)) , x to infty it's seems also doesn't exist ?

Comment: @user51189 indeed, it doesn't exist

Comment: It would seem I've had an anonymous downvote. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: no idea why someone would downvote your answer, in fact I give a +1 since I think it adds the right heuristic. Maybe you could mention $|i|=1$ which makes it straightforward impossible to converge to $0$, but that's all